# serve http content under ssl

Tags: html, ssl, flash

i want to serve world clock into my SSL enabled website. when i use http chrome browser shows mixed content "this page include other resources which are not secure"

the clock url is: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=FF6633&wtsid=MY&

already try SSL proxy to display clock but no luck:
https://ssl-proxy.my-addr.net/myaddrproxy.php/http/www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf?color=FF6633&wtsid=MY&

this shows Clock fault. Undefined! Undefined.

also uploading that flash clock into web server and undefined error also occur.

is there anything should i try or any recommendation ssl enabled clock similiar to worldtimeserver to use?

**updates:**

javascript looks nicer http://randomibis.com/coolclock/

thanks to Graham

Comment: Contact the company and find out if they have a different hostname / subdomain for SSL traffic.

Comment: good idea thanks. already tried https://worldtimer.com ssl not enabled  on that site. maybe there are another domain that support ssl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what proxy you're using, but it's entirely possible that you need to escape the "?" and "&" characters so they won't be interpreted by myaddrproxy.php and will instead be passed to the proxied URL.

```
https://ssl-proxy.my-addr.net/myaddrproxy.php/http/www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/wtsclock001.swf%3fcolor=FF6633%26wtsid=MY
```

Buy as I say, I don't know your proxy script; you may have to experiment with how to escape special characters.

Or read the instructions from the proxy script.  :-)

Comment: the proxy is free one. you can search ssl proxy in google and this come first. :)

Comment: i just want to embed working clock into my ssl enabled website so that mixed content warning not showing.

Comment: Then why not do it in JavaScript, which you can include on your site, rather than using proxy software to slurm closed-source proprietary Flash code from somebody whose web site is not under your control?  There are plenty of [cool JavaScript clocks](http://randomibis.com/coolclock/) around.  No Flash required, no proxy required.

Comment: +1 for doing it in JavaScript.  Just Say No to closed-source proprietary "web" technology.  Flash is so ... 90's.